# I have two buttons on a page, save and complete. I'm looking for two different alerts for two input fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

If the value of the input box for charge_amt is not entered I'm using an onbeforeunload jquery event which notifys the user they didn't enter an amount. After they enter the amount they are allowed to save.

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="charge_cc" value="0" class="">
        <input type="checkbox" id="charge_cc" name="charge_cc" value="1" checked="" class=""> Charge CC? Amount $ <input type="text" id="charge_amt" name="charge_amt" value="523" size="8" maxlength="6"></td>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='text'], select, textarea").change(function(){
        window.onbeforeunload = function()
            {
            return "You have not saved an amount to be charged.";
            }
    });
    $("charge_amt").submit(function(){

        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
});
</script>
```

The second event is for the complete button.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='reorder_comment_for_CC'> Verify Charge and Leave Comment" ?>
```

If they go to hit complete but this checkbox hasn't been marked i would like to alert them that they will not be able to complete the event without verifying/checking.

Maybe I should just use two separate events like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#charge_amt").keypress(function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 1) {
         return "You have not input an amount to be charged.";
    } else {
         return "Thank you for entering a charge amount, you can now save.";
    }
});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check both if the user has entered a correct value in charge_amt and if they have checked the checkbox like this. You also seem to be a little confused about the jQuery syntax. You should use #the_id_of_the_element to find a single element. The `submit()` event is attached to your form not to the field `charge_atm`.

```
$("#id_of_your_form").submit(function() {
    //Here you can check the checkbox
    //This assumes you add the id of the checkbox to be the same as the name
    var $checked = $(this).find("#reorder_comment_for_CC").is(":checked");
    var $validValue = $(this).find("#charge_amt").val().length > 0;        

    if (!$checked) {
       alert("You haven't verified charge");
       return false;//prevent submitting
    }

    if (!$validValue) {
        alert("Invalid value");
        return false;
    }

   return true;

});
```